# Modularizing an Express/Socket.io application

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I want to be able to load these 4 functions: `returnAvailable`, `processMessage`, `removeUser` and `joinRoom` from an external file, but i get reference errors where it says that socket and nicknames are undefined. How do I modularize my app with respect to dependencies I use?

Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// mongoDB init
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/chat");
var Message = require('./server/datasets/message');

//include these 4 functions
var util = require('./server/util/util');

//object which contains all users and chatrooms
var nicknames = {
    'Music': [], 
    'Videogames': [], 
    'Sports': [], 
    'TV': [],
    'Politics': []
};

// middleware
// serves static files
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));


// routes
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

app.get('/api/rooms/get', function(req, res){
    res.json(nicknames);
});


server.listen(2000);


// socket functionality
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('new user', util.returnAvailable);

    // do when 'send message' data is received from client
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        util.processMessage(data);
    });

    // do when 'disconnect' data is received from the client
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        util.removeUser();
    });

    socket.on('leave room', function(){
        util.removeUser();
    });

});
```

**util.js**

```
module.exports.returnAvailable = function (data, callback){
    console.log(data);

    if(nicknames[data.room].indexOf(data.username) != -1){
        callback({ bool: false });
    }else {
        socket.nickname = data.username;
        joinRoom(socket, data.room);

        nicknames[data.room].push(socket.nickname);
        console.log(nicknames[data.room]);

        io.sockets.to(data.room).emit('usernames', nicknames[data.room]);
        callback({ bool: true, nickname: socket.nickname});
    }
}

module.exports.removeUser = function(){
    //console.log(socket.nickname + " disconnected. Bool value: " + socket.nickname==true);
    if(socket.nickname==false) return;
    // socket.room has to be defined, otherwise crashes if user reloads while not in a roomn
    if(socket.room)
    {
        nicknames[socket.room].splice(nicknames[socket.room].indexOf(socket.nickname), 1);
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    }

    io.sockets.to(socket.room).emit('usernames', nicknames[socket.room]);
}

module.exports.joinRoom = function (data){
    socket.join(data);
    socket.room = data;
    console.log(socket.room);

    var query = Message.find({room: socket.room});
    query.sort({created:-1}).limit(5).exec(function(err, results){
        if(err) { console.log(err); }

        else if(results){ 
            io.sockets.to(socket.room).emit('old messages', results); 
        }
    });
}


module.exports.processMessage = function(data){
    io.sockets.to(socket.room).emit('new message', {msg : data, nick : socket.nickname});
    var message = new Message({
        created: new Date,
        user: socket.nickname,
        message: data,
        room: socket.room
    });

    message.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('Successfully saved.');
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using Express 4.13.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `socket` variable is only available within `io.sockets.on('connection',` callback function so you can't use it in other files this easily. But you can pass the `socket` variable to the function where you are trying to use it like this

```
util.removeUser(socket);
```

and change the definition of `removeUser` to accept the socket as an argument

```
module.exports.removeUser = function(socket){

    // your code here

}
```

The same goes for `nicknames` variable, use it like this

```
socket.on('new user', function(data) {

    util.returnAvailable(io, socket, nicknames, data);

});
```

and change the function to accept those arguments

```
module.exports.returnAvailable = function (io, socket, nicknames, data){

    // your code here

}
```

Comment: Great, works for processMessage and removeUser functions. How do I pass socket and nickname arguments to returnAvailable function which is used as a callback?
This is the new function definition 
    returnAvailable = function (io, socket, nicknames, data, callback){}.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, the function returnAvailable calls the other function joinRoom. But it's undefined when I export these 4 functions like this. Also undefined if I try to call it as util.joinRoom. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two ways to solve it, either use `module.exports.joinRoom(socket, io)` or define your function like this `function joinRoom (){ ... }` and at the bottom of util.js export it like this `module.exports.joinRoom = joinRoom;` this way you can call it just with `joinRoom(socket, io)`